# Why does print not work, if I do not get any errors or warnings(python)?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, lambda, printing

I'm kinda new to python. I want to write a code which can produce the legendre polinomials for me.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
from scipy import integrate
p=int(input("p="))
arr = [0]*(p+1)
a = [0]*(p+1)
arr[0]=lambda x: 1
arr[1]=lambda x: x
for i in range(2,p+1):
    arr[i]=lambda x:2*i*x*arr[i-1](x)-(i-1)*arr[i-2](x)/i
    a[i]=arr[i](0)
print(a[p])
```

The code does not give any errors or warnings. I wanted to check if the code calculates well, so I tried to print one of the legendre polinomials with an exact value (zero). It works well if p<3, but if p>3 the code does not print anything, but I don't get errors or warnings, so I don't know what hte problem is. p is the degree of the legendre polinomial. If p=3 I should get the first four legendre polinomial(because they also start from zero, like the indexing of lists).I also tried printing the value directly without the list *a*, but that didn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: The `i` is bound to the *last* value of `i`, i.e.`p`. That is not what you want. Use `lambda x, i=i: ...` to capture the *current* value of `i`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do lambda function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)